# Renaming column name in excel after populating data from gridview

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

I have a dashboard which is a gridview. I've a button to export the gridview data to excel which is already working fine. The only problem is that the column names are not user friendly and I want to change it while populating the data from the gridview.

The column name of the gridview is not coming to the excel at all. It's just reading the column names as which is there in the datatable.

please help.

Thanks in advance,
ThunderRock

Comment: I am looking at using xsl for the renaming part but not sure how to go about this...

Comment: HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DashBoardData.xls");
        StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);        grdDashboard.DataSource = dtResults;
        grdDashboard.DataBind();
        form.Controls.Add(grdDashboard);
        this.Controls.Add(form);
        form.RenderControl(htextw);       
        Response.Write(stw.ToString());
        Response.End();

Comment: That's my code currently for populating the excel from the gridview...